# Enable versioning on SPList programmatically

Tags: list, versioning, splist, version-history

I am trying to enable version history on a regular task list programmatically which is possible from the UI, but how can this be achieved in code?

I assumed setting `EnableVersioning = true` would do the trick, but it does not work.

According to msdn:

> Although the EnableVersioning property is defined on the SPList class, versioning is only available for document library lists."

Answer (score 3):

I've used code like this in a console app where I was reconfiguring some lists. This enables versioning and sets limits.

```
var depts = web.Lists.TryGetList("Depts");
                    if (depts != null)
                    {
                        depts.EnableModeration = true;
                        depts.EnableVersioning = true;
                        depts.MajorVersionLimit = 1;
                        depts.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit = 1;
                        depts.DraftVersionVisibility = DraftVisibilityType.Author;
                        depts.Update();
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.WriteLine("Versioning enabled on the department list successfully.");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably forgot to call [SPList.Update method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.update(v=office.15).aspx) to apply the changes, for example:

```
var tasksList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Tasks");
tasksList.EnableVersioning = true;
tasksList.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Versioning on lists can also be `Enabled/Disabled` using `PowerShell`. I have used this `CSOM PowerShell` function to enable versioning on a custom list. Since its a CSOM you need not run this on server, i.e. you can execute this function remotely provided you have installed Client APIs

```
Try{
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll'
}

catch {
    Throw "Unable to load SharePoint Client runtime"
}

function Enable-VersioningOnList()
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$listName
    )
    begin{
        try
        {
            #get Client Object
            $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
            $context.Credentials = $credentials
            $web = $context.Web 
            $context.Load($web) 
            $context.ExecuteQuery()

            #Retrieve List
            $List = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
            $context.Load($List)
            $context.ExecuteQuery()


        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "Error while getting context. Error -->> "  + $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    process{
        try
        {
            # To disable use $false else if to enable use $true
            $list.EnableVersioning = $true
            $list.Update()
            $context.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-Host "Versioning enabled on " $List.Title " successfully" -ForegroundColor Green

        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "Error while disabling versioning. Error -->> "  + $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    end{
        $context.Dispose()
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
Enable-VersioningOnList "http://yoursite" $credentials "ListTitle"
```